# Flex changing the dataProvider of a chart

Tags: apache-flex

when I double click on a chart, I want to change the dataProvider:

```
  public function myListener(e:ChartItemEvent):void {
    mainDataProvider = e.hitData.item.costsByNature;
    pieSeries.nameField="natureLabel";
    pieSeries.field="amount";
 }
```

When I execute, I get an error :
amount property is not found on ProjectDTO and there is no default value.

The previous dataProvider was an arrayCollection with element s type: ProjectDTO
but I want to change it to an arrayCollection with element's type CostByNatureDTO.

CostByNatureDTO has amount as a property

how can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create an interface which both these models would implement.  E.g.,

```
public interface IFooBar {
  function get myLabel():String;
  function get myAmount():Number;
}



public class CostsByNature implements IFooBar {
  //your code here
  public var natureLabel:String;
  public var amount:String;


  public function get myLabel():String {
     return this.natureLabel;
  }

  public function get myAmount():Number {
    return this.amount;
  }
}


public class ProjectDTO implements IFooBar {
  //your code here
  public var projectLabel:String;
  public var projectAmount:String;


  public function get myLabel():String {
     return this.projectLabel;
  }

  public function get myAmount():Number {
    return this.projectAmount;
  }
}
```

In your pie chart, always bind to "myLabel" and "myAmount."  And in your pie chart's listener, switch between the dataProviders.

```
public function myListener(e:ChartItemEvent):void {
    mainDataProvider = e.hitData.item.costsByNature;
 }
```

Good luck!